# javscript function, that ouput's 1 when input changes from 1 to 0 (positive flank)

Tags: javascript, triggers

I want to create a function, that output's a 1 whenever the input changes from 0 to 1.

Here's a picture for visualization of the event.

Can someone help me?

[Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn3MF.png)

Comment: Hi Oliver and welcome to SO. If you are new here please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which explains SO for newcomers. At the moment your question lacks code, context and a general problem statement. Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and specifically the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make your question as clear as possible. This will increase the chance of getting a good answer more likely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need, you need a function that remembers the previous value passed to it, and only when there is a change from 0 to 1, return 1. That can be achieved with a *closure*.

Basicaly a "builder" function returns another function, the returned function has access to variables declared in the "buider" function. Those variables retain their value from one invocation of the returned function to another.

```js
function build(initial) {
    let previous = initial;
    return function(input) {
        const output = previous === 0 && input === 1 ? 1 : 0;
        previous = input;
        return output;
    }
}

const values = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];

const positiveFlank = build();

for (const value of values) {
  const output = positiveFlank(value);
  console.log(`Input ${value}`, `Output ${output}`);
}
```